# Kri / K'tiv - Why were they created to start?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, torah-writing

There are numerous places in the Torah (as well as the rest of Tanac"h) that have *ktiv / kri* conflicts. The word is written one way but pronounced differently.

For example, Numbers 1:16:

> אֵ֚לֶּה **קריאי** [קְרוּאֵ֣י] הָעֵדָ֔ה נְשִׂיאֵ֖י מַטּ֣וֹת אֲבוֹתָ֑ם
>   רָאשֵׁ֛י אַלְפֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל הֵֽם׃

These were the elect of the congregation, the princes of the tribes of their fathers; they were the heads of the thousands of Israel.

(I've left the English translation for M.Y. reader's info)

In the above sample, the bold word is how it is written in the Torah, and the bracketed word is how it is read.

I assume that when Moses wrote the Torah, G-d communicated each word that Moshe was supposed to write them down. I think it's safe to assume that Moshe knew how to spell Hebrew words (and while he did have speech problems, his hearing was fine ;-) So, when it came to *kri / ktiv* situations such as the one above, did G-d say, "No, Moshe. I want you to write the word THIS way, but you'll tell everyone that it really is supposed to be said THAT way?" How did these conflicts originate, and what was the purpose of having them? Why not make it consistent to start?

(I'm uncertain of how to tag this question.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few explanations for this. regarding the Keri oChtev in the Torah, the Gmara says (Nedarim 37):> אמר רבי יצחק: מקרא סופרים, וקריין ולא כתיבן וכתיבן ולא קריין (=היינו, 'קרי ולא כתיב' ו'כתיב ולא קרי'), הלכה למשה מסיני. 
In other words, the differences were given already when the Torah was written. the reason that is given in Megila 25 is that the Torah wanted to speak in clean language even if it was written differently:> כל המקראות הכתובין בתורה לגנאי קורין אותן לשבח, כגון ישגלנה - ישכבנה.

Although, the  Radak in his introduction to  Neviim writes that the reason is because that Chazal had different versions of the Bible and they weren't sure which is correct:

> נראה כי מלות האלה נמצאו כן לפי שבגלות ראשונה אבדו הספרים ונטלטלו. והחכמים יודעי התורה מתו ואנשי כנסת הגדולה שהחזירו עטרה ליושנה מצאו מחלוקת בספרים, והלכו בהם אחר הרוב לפי דעתם; ובמקום שלא השיגה דעתם על הבירור, כתבו האחד ולא נקדו או כתבו מבחוץ ולא כתבו מבפנים, וכן כתבו בדרך אחד מבפנים ובדרך אחר מבחוץ...

The Abarbanal on the other hand claims that they originated when Ezra edited the Tanach:

> עצתם רחקה ממני כי איך אוכל בנפשי להאמין ואיך אעלה על שפתי שמצא עזרא הסופר ספר תורת האלוקים וספרי נביאיו ושאר המדברים ברוח הקודש מסופקים בהפסק ובלבול, וספר תורה שחסר ממנו אות אחת פסול, וכל שכן בקרי וכתיב שבאו בתורה... יחסרו כמה וכמה מהאותיות. והנה זאת נחמתנו בענייננו שתורת השם אתנו בגלותנו... העניין אצלי הוא שעזרא ואנשי כנסת הגדולה מצאו ספרי התורה בשלמותם ותמותם כמו שנכתבו... עזרא עיין במקרא והדברים נראו אליו זרים כפי טבע הלשון וכוונת הסיפור וחשב שהיה זה לאחד מב' סיבות: אם שכיוון הכותב בדברים הזרים ההם סוד מן הסודות מסתרי התורה כפי מעלת נבואתו ועומק חכמתו ולכן לא מלאו ידו לגשת ידיו למחוק דבר מספרי האלוקים... כי הבין בדעתו שבחכמה יתירה נכתבו כן... ולכן הניחם בכתב מבפנים כמו שנכתב, האומנם שם מבחוץ הקרי שהוא פירוש הכתוב הזר ההוא, כפי טבעו הלשון ופשיטות העניין.